How to understand restriction mapping a quarter of a century later?
Today, biology is virtually all based on massively parallel sequencing, long-strand sequencing, and metagenomic; looking back at old restriction mapping is not straightforward (at least for me).
For instance, in this seminal paper (Marini and Landy, Virology 1977;76:196 - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0042682277902963), the authors used essentially three enzymes (Hinc, Hind II, Hind III) to determine the position of the "common core" of homology between Escherichia coli and lambda phage genomes that allows homology recombination, a segment known as att site. The phage att site was called POP’ and the bacteria att site was called POB’.
They had available two classes of phage mutants:

One class is comprised of those phage which carry a prophage att site
in place of the normal phage att site.  The second class of mutant
phage, designated POΔ’ and ΔOP’, carry partial phage att sites. The
“Δ” indicates the “non-att” DNA which has been transposed to lie
adjacent to the common core by the deletion event.

The authors also reasoned that

To identify the att-containing Hind fragment, 11 deletion mutants of A
centering around the crossover region for integration were used. Three
of the deletions extend rightward from “0” [att] and should thus be
missing the P’ arm of the att site. These comprise the POA’ class of
mutants.  Five of the deletions extend leftward from “0”. They should
be missing the left arm of the att site and are designated ΔOP’
mutants.  Two others contain deletions that began to the left of att
and continue past att on the right; thus, these crossover deletions
lack the entire POP’ region.  A final mutant has a deletion slightly
offset to the left of the att site. Every rightward deletion mutant,
should lack the Hind fragment that contains the att site, since a
portion of the site is in the deleted region of all POΔ’ phage.
Similarly, the mutants with deletions extending to the left would fail
to generate some of the wild-type restriction products.

And now for the punch line:

The Hind wild-type fragment containing POP’ [the core element of att,
that is "O"] would be identified by virtue of the fact that it would
be the only fragment missing from both rightward and leftward deletion
mutants.

They drew an ideal map associated with these concepts:

Is it possible to explain such reasoning in a more accessible way?
Thank you

You'd need to read the rest of the paper - it is explained what each of the mutants should contain, which is the essential piece of information needed to understand the figure. Particularly the para that encompasses the bottom of the left column and the top of the right on the same page as the fig.

I echo the remarks made by @bob1. We can't understand the "ideal map" without the figure legend and the context of the text. I have no idea what the horizontal bars are meant to represent or the C2, C4 etc. Restriction mapping itself is a pure logical exercise, for which no biological knowledge is required. Now or yesterday. The difficulty here is integrating it with the information one has about the DNA fragment on which the digestion have been performed. This is not a journal club, so this problem isn't really suitable for a Q&A list like this.

Sorry, I should have added the legend. It just says that the bar represents the lack of a restriction fragment, so the map is a kind of negative film. I also understand this is not a j. Club, just wanted to understand better the last sentence: why should the fragment of interest be the one missing from the mutants.
